# What's the use of defining a streamline?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, continuum-mechanics

Streamlines by definition are field lines corresponding to the velocity field.
when bringing the equation of streamlines we apply the condition that says that the velocity is collinear with the streamline.

what defines the streamline from the first place? Isn't it the velocity field? I mean the velocity field alone has a defined direction , what's the use of the streamline and what causes it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A streamline is the path of one particle. Yes, it is defined by the velocity field, which essentially just a description of the motion (velocities) of *all* particles at *all* points. Pick one of those particles and follow it from start to end, and you have a streamline.

Streamlines are nothing but a visualization. They give us a sense of the flow "quality" (for example laminar or turbulent).

As commented by @Tofi, I am actually only considering steady flow in this description. A streamline equals the actual path only under steady-flow conditions.

Think of you driving through morning traffic:

- Initially, your GPS calculates a path. **This is a streamline**.
- During the trip the path it calculates might change, because traffic changes, and you end up taking another path than the initially planned streamline. **Every time it changes, this is a new streamline**.
- The actual path you end up taking **is the pathline**.

If the conditions don't change along the way, the streamline is constant all the way and end up being equal to the path taken.

Comment: Note that streamlines are generally [different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streamlines,_streaklines,_and_pathlines) from pathlines, except for the case of a steady flow.

Comment: Thank you Steeven. But isn't the streamline of a particle just the velocity of that particle ?

Comment: Thank Tofi, I added that important note to the answer and gave an analogy to differentiate those two terms. @ZahraaKhalife, yes it is. The streamline is the path a particle will take due to the velocity field. If this velocity field changes, then the streamline changes.

Comment: Thank you Steeven :)  And @Tofi thank you for the link am still reading it , its good :)

Answer (score 2):

The value of using the stream function is that it reduces the number of dependent variables you have to deal with (the two velocity components) to one, while, at the same time reducing the number of equations required  by one (eliminating the continuity equation).  I would say that's a pretty big advantage.